# Generate PowerPoint based on template with data from csv file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, csv, slideshow

I'd like to create a simple slideshow, each slide has an image, plays an audio file, and has a title. I have the data in a csv file that looks like this:

**Hello,aud001.mp3,img001.jpg**

Any suggestions how to do this? I know you can create a PhotoAlbum from in PowerPoint. How to insert sound and text from csv?

Any suggestions appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, coding that using Visual Basic or Visual Basic for Applications may be easiest (if not only) way to do it.

There is some (not-so-good) examples around, for example [this blog post](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2006/07/vba-creating-powerpoint-presentation.html) and [Microsoft Knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222929).